# Swift CollectionView crashes app when elements are removed from shared data source

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have an application which displays data in a few different ways, one of which is a collection view.

The CollectionView displays data from an array which is located in another ViewController. That other ViewController is responsible for adding and deleting elements to and from the array.

After an element is deleted, and reloadData() is called the app crashes. I've tried various methods to delete the cell which is displaying the deleted data before reloadData() is called, but I can't seem to get anything to work.

The only thing I'm seeing in the console is:
*** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionViewData validateLayoutInRect:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit/UIKit-3599.6/UICollectionViewData.m:433

Any relevant info would be much appreciated

Comment: Could you show some code of what you're doing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up finding the solution. I was implementing a custom UICollectionViewLayout, in which I stored the attributes for each cell in an array.

The problem was that my initial implementation was not designed to handle a dynamic data source (adding/removing elements after initialization).

Although the cells were being deleted, the layout attributes still remained.

Once I addressed this the CollectionView properly dynamically added and removed items.